# Как установить междустрочный интервал Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Нужно увеличить высоту строк в многострочном тексте `QLabel`.
 Но, не нашел решения с `QFont` и `QStyleSheets`. Как это сделать?

```
auto progNameLabel = new QLabel(tr("Text text text text text..."), leftPanel);
progNameLabel->setWordWrap(true);
```

Comment: Похожий вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749612/qlabel-interlinea-linespacing-in-wordwrap-mode

Comment: @Unick получилось это сделать через `HTML`, но надеялся что есть другие варианты.